# Can't call WCF service from WebApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I have a simple WCF SOAP service hosted at company's Data Center, having just one Method that receives a Guid (for identifying the request), and returns nothing (void). We use this method as a signal for the service to load its configuration from Database. The service is a self-hosted WCF using SOAP and it is running as a WindowsService.

This service is called from a ASP.NET Web Application, when the user changes configurations related to him. The database is updated, and the service is called to load its updated settings.

The problem is, this service suddenly can't be accessed anymore from the application in production. I get a 404 error, BUT when opening WSDL from browser inside the application's machine, it loads normally.

Trying to reproduce the problem, I created Console Application just to call it from my development machine and it works. BUT, if I try to call it from a new Web Application, another problem happens: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond".

Also, if I make a call using SoapUI or Visual Studio's WCF Test Client, I can connect without any problem.

For all tests, I used the same approach to made the client: Create a Service Reference (Visual Studio generated code tool). The code used to call the service is something like that:

```
using (var client = new NotificatorClient())
{
    var request = new NotifyRequest { RequestId = Guid.NewGuid() };
    client.Notify(request); // Works from any project that is not a WebApplication
    Label1.Text = "Notificated!";
}
```

For all clients, my system.ServiceModel section of Web.config is the same (working on anything that is not a WebApplication, as I said):

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INotificator">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://myservice.com"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INotificator"
        contract="MyAppNotificatorSvc.INotificator" name="BasicHttpBinding_INotificator" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Also, here's my service contracts, if it helps to understand better any problem that could be happening.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INotificator
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Notify(NotifyRequest request);
}

[DataContract]
public class NotifyRequest
{
    [DataMember(Name = "RequestId", Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
    public Guid RequestId { get; set; }
}
```

We are using HTTPS with TLS 1.2 as our security protocol over requests, and Itried to change it by calling this code on the WebApplication, but I still have the same problem.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I know that this may sound like not really relevant information about the problem, but this is as far as I got until now. Does anyone came into this type of problem? Any tip on what could be happening?

Comment: When it comes to WCF troubleshooting, unless you have [Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx) enabled, all you're doing is guesswork.

Comment: Thanks, @jstreet, I will try this.